# How to run multiple threads in Ubuntu?

Tags: multithreading, c++11

I decided to learn how to program multiple threads.  I am running Ubuntu 12.04 which had gcc 4.6 installed originally.  I installed gcc version 5 and switched to it. So when I do g++ --version it shows that I am using version 5.2.1.  The I wrote a program to launch two threads and tried to compile it with g++ -std=c++11 thread.cpp but I get:

```
/tmp/ccAP5xoU.o:thread.cpp:function _ZNSt6threadC1IRFvvEJEEEOT_DpOT0_: error: undefined reference to 'pthread_create'
```

collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Here's the program:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>

void hello() {
    std::cout << "Hello Strings!\n";
}

int main()
{
    std::thread t(hello);
    t.join();
}
```

What could be the problem?

Comment: You must add `-pthread` compiler switch.

Comment: @n.m. Thanks, that worked for command shell.  Would you happen to know where to include that in Eclipse?

Comment: @n.m nvm I had to include pthread lib in Eclipse.  Thanks again.